# ImportError: No module named extern, when using easy_install

Tags: python, terminal, pip, sudo, easy-install

So I was minding my own business trying to install Gensim for Python.  First I found myself blocked by an outdated version of setuptools.

After a half hour of googling I somehow got a newer version of setuptools installed.

After that I was able to successfully install Gensim, but when I went into Python to try to import it it said `no module named Queue`.  Ok no problem, so I try to install Queue, but I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named extern
```

Ok no problem, I try to install `extern`, but I get the same error.

After about an hour and a half more of googling I can't figure out what to do, also at some point I accidentally deleted `pip`.  And when I try to reinstall it, I still get the `ImportError`. What should I do?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/easy_install", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==27.2.0', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 357, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2394, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2108, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.11-intel/egg/setuptools/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.11-intel/egg/setuptools/extern/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named extern
```

Comment: so `easy_install pip` is returning the import error you pasted above? Also, I tried `import Queue`, and it worked, so it must be a built-in module.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem on Ubuntu 16.04, and solved it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-setuptools
```

Try an analogue OSX command.